# Spock test in gradle could not be configured in a separate sourceSet

Tags: gradle, groovy, spock

I have been trying to configure spock in the gradle project. So with the following configuration, it works out.

apply plugin: 'groovy'

My test cases are in the folder `src/test/groovy`. This works fine.I am able to run the test case.

However , I want to separate the integration tests into a separate folder structure - `src/itest/groovy`.

For this I added the following:

```
sourceSets {

  itest {
    srcDir file('src/itest/groovy')
  }
  resourceDir ..
  compileClassPath ..
}

configurations {
  itestCompile.extendsfrom testCompile
}
```

I am not able to copy the entire code here because of org restrictions. But I did try what all variations I could get online and it did not work!!

I always got the error:

```
The task compileItestGroovy was not found in the project.
```

I did some research and this task is added by the groovy plugin by default. Still the task could not be found and my build is in limbo. It would be great if you could help me up with this.

P.S This project also has other plugins such as java as the source code is in java.

Command to run - ./gradlew clean build

Gradle version - 2.2.1

I tried similar set up on my home pc with gradle version 3.5 and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Given the following `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

sourceSets {
    integration {
        groovy {
            compileClasspath += main.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output
            srcDirs = ['src/integration/groovy']
        }
        resources.srcDir file('src/integration/resources')
    }
}

configurations {
    // By default, integration tests have the same dependencies as standard tests
    integrationCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    integrationRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.12'
    testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4'

    // This is only available for the integration tests
    integrationCompile 'com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine:2.5.5'
}

tasks.create('integrationTest', Test) {
    dependsOn 'compileIntegrationGroovy'
    group = 'Verification'
    description = 'Runs the integration tests'

    // GRADLE 2.2
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.integration.output.classesDir

    // GRADLE 3.5
    // testClassesDirs = sourceSets.integration.output.classesDirs

    classpath = sourceSets.integration.runtimeClasspath
}

tasks.findByName('check').dependsOn 'integrationTest'
```

You should be able to stick integration tests inside `src/integration/groovy` and `./gradlew check` will run both the standard tests, AND the integration tests

Comment: Should have worked. I get the same exception though. My project uses gradle 2.2.1. Not sure if something is happening because of that. I have used similar set up for 3.5 and that works like a charm. But here- the same exception

Comment: Why didn't you mention that in the question? You don't even say what your exception is.  You don't even say clearly what you're running to get the mystery exception...

Comment: @user3276247 Ok. I tried the above in 2.2.1, and made an adjustment to the test task at the bottom... Fingers crossed